# How to build gi-gtk package on Windows 10 with stack

Tags: haskell, gtk3, haskell-stack

I am unable to build a test Haskell 2010 program which depends on package `gi-gtk` with `stack` on Windows 10. Any guidance on how to do that would be appreciated.

Specifically, `stack build` fails at/after dependency `gi-gdk-3.0.3: configure` with message:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\MIKEPI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\stack2692\gi-gdk-3.0.3\Setup.hs, C:\Users\MIKEPI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\stack2692\gi-gdk-3.0.3\.stack-work\dist\b7fec021\setup\Main.o )
Linking C:\Users\MIKEPI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\stack2692\gi-gdk-3.0.3\.stack-work\dist\b7fec021\setup\setup.exe ...
GI\Gdk\Structs\EventProximity.hs: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument
(invalid character)
```

The context is `stack` version 1.2.0, `resolver: lts-7.8` (GHC 8.0.1) and Windows 10 Version 10.0.14393 - using Command Prompt with active code page: 65001 and font DejaVu Sans Mono. I mention the latter because I've read elsewhere that 'invalid argument (invalid character)' can be something to do with Unicode. With code page 65001, `localeEncoding` is UTF-8.

The following environmental variables have been set:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig
XDG_DATA_DIRS=C:\msys64\mingw64\share
```

in light of this wiki page: [Using haskell gi in Windows](https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi/wiki/Using-haskell-gi-in-Windows)

Revised Update: experimenting with a local copy of the package, it appears that what is giving rise to the problem is 'smart' single or double quotation mark characters in `*.gir` files at (on my system) `C:\msys64\mingw64\share\gir-1.0`. For example, a 'Right Single Quotation Mark' (U+2019) character. The files affected in my case are `Gdk-3.0.gir` and `Gtk-3.0.gir`. The translation of those '*.gir' files into `*.hs` files appears to abort at the point where the first 'smart' quotation character is encountered.

Comment: Someone somewhere is probably missing `hSetEncoding stdout utf8`... I think this is default on many systems, which is why it would've been missed up until now.

Comment: @Alec, I think that 'somewhere' must be `stack`, as `cabal install gi-gtk` seems to work eventually (it stalled a few times on the way). What I don't follow is that, with active code page: 65001, `localeEncoding` (which I understand to be the default when a Handle is created) is already `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

With `haskell-gi-0.20` etc provided under `resolver: nightly-2016-12-08` this is no longer an issue requiring a work around.

---

My original work around for the specific error identified in the question was to edit the `*.gir` files. I found 'smart' quotation characters and replaced them with the corresponding ASCII characters.